# Stabilizing inverter output shift using an RC circuit

Tags: voltage, power, circuit-analysis, capacitor, resistors

I have an MD-40 pump which runs on 230V AC output from an inverter. The pump squeals and stops working properly when the main supply is back after an outage and the inverter output shifts back to the mains input.

I'm assuming that this is happening because the inverter output voltage drops to 0 for a long enough time during the shift ing process.

Only this very inverter make causes this problem with this pump. The problem is also not specific to this pump unit; I tried with different units of the same model with the same result.

Having heard about snubber circuits, I'm thinking a simple RC circuit can possibly solve the problem. I'm new to analog circuit design, so bear with me.

Here's my thought process: a capacitor charging through a resistor will not let the voltage across it to rise or fall quickly. The pertinent factor is the time constant (RC) of the circuit. Considering that we have 230V 50Hz on the inverter output, I should choose an RC that'll charge the capacitor faster than the rate at which the voltage changes, or else I risk filtering out the voltage. It should also be much slower than the rate at which the voltage drops when there's a shift, so that there's still some voltage across the output which can drive the pump when there's a shift.

I'm wondering if I should calculate R and C to get a t = RC, or some factor of RC considering that RC represents the time it takes for the capacitor to charge to 63.2% of the maximum value. Looking this up further online led to frequency domain analysis and obscure symbols that I do not really understand.

I'm also having a hard time believing if this circuit will work properly, considering that I'm going by the assumption that the voltage drop is much faster than 50Hz and there'll be an area where I can base my capacitor voltage on. I'm also obviously wondering about all the innumerable things that I'm not thinking about, being a noob.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> *I have an MD-40 pump which runs on 230V AC output from an inverter.
> The pump squeals and stops working properly when the main supply is
> back after an outage and the inverter output shifts back to the mains
> input.*

Your assumption may be incorrect.

When the mains comes back, it may come back with an initial low AC voltage for some seconds or minutes. But, the inverter may choose to "use" the low AC voltage immediately but, it may still be too low to properly drive the pump and, the pump stalls and squeals.

The inverter **should only** switch back to mains AC power once it has been established that it's back to normal (230 volts) AC levels. This may require some form of AC level detector or, it may mean that the inverter might not be suitable. Maybe even a delay circuit that waits a couple of minutes before switching to AC power might be a good feature to add.

After all, if the inverter is not driving the pump (due to it being deactivated) and there is normal AC levels at the power input to the inverter, does the pump have any problem starting and running when reactivated. Think about it.

> *Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.*

You need to justify your assumption in order to get to the truth of what is happening. Either way; it has probably nothing to do with snubbers.

Comment: I want to clarify a few things: 1. The inverter is a ready-made one from the market; 2. Mains supply comes back instantaneously with full 230V. The problem is with the inverter's output. A different make inverter doesn't cause the pump to malfunction. 3. My ignorance made me use the word "snubber" loosely. My intention is to make a circuit that I can connect to the inverter output to resolve this issue. I was only thinking about the capacitor's ability to suppress voltage fluctuations. A colleague of mine said he solved this issue by connecting a capacitor in parallel to the output supply.

Comment: I want to develop that simple parallel capacitor into a reliable circuit.

Comment: Sounds to me like an inverter problem either a one-off or a design problem. If the pump works fine when activated via the inverter when already powered by mains then it's not the pump and guessing how to add something to the output that may or may not be snubber-like doesn't sound promising as a way forward. Find the root cause then design a fix or, swap out the inverter @nottherealfaraday

Comment: Yes, the pump has no issues at all when the power switches to inverter when there's a mains fail. Can you please explain why you don't think the capacitor solution isn't promising. Finding the root cause would mean tearing the inverter apart, and I'd still don't know what to look for, with my level of experience. This setup is used in many of our company's sites. Replacing all those inverters isn't being considered right now.